# Решение 23 задачи проекта Эйлера на python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Решаю [23 задачу](https://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/23.html) из проекта Эйлера. Моя идея состоит в том, что перебирая все числа от 1 до 28123, я нахожу среди них избыточные и добавляю в список, а затем проверяю, может ли число быть представлено, как сумма двух избыточных чисел из этого списка. Если может, то я вычитаю это число из суммы всех чисел от 1 до 28123. Таким образом, в сухом остатке я должен получить сумму чисел, которые не могут быть представлены как сумма двух избыточных чисел. Реализация на языке:

```
array = []
summ = 0

for i in range (1, 28123):
    summ += i

for i in range (4, 28123):

    print ("Идет обработка числа ", i)

    if i % 2 == 0:
        n = 1
        j = 2
        limit = i // 2
        if limit in array:
            array.append (i)
            continue
    else:
        n = 2
        j = 3
        limit = i // 3

    sum_dividers = 1

    while (sum_dividers <= i) and (j <= limit):
        if i % j == 0:
            sum_dividers += j
        j += n

    if sum_dividers > i:
        array.append (i)

    mean = i // 2

    for j in array:
        if (i - j) in array:
            summ -= i
            break
        elif j > mean:
            break

print (summ)
```

Во втором цикле я начинаю с числа 4, так как ни 1, ни 2, ни 3 - не избыточные числа, и не могут быть представлены как сумма двух избыточных чисел. А прописывать для них отдельные случаи я не вижу смысла.

Я понимаю, что мой код плохо оптимизирован, над этим я буду работать потом. Сейчас меня интересует, почему он выдает неправильный ответ? Верное решение - 4179871, мой код говорит, что 53218451, то есть разница огромная. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема в операторе `continue`. Когда он выполняется у строчки `summ -= i` нет шансов выполнится и убрать соответствующее число. Если копию цикла `for j in array:` вставить перед `continue`, то ваша программа выдаст верный результат.

Вот быстрое решение. Применены решето Эратосфена с делителями, мультипликативность суммы делителей, два представления для множества избыточных чисел:

```
def make_sieve(n):
    sieve = [0] * n
    for i in range(2, n):
        if sieve[i] == 0:
            sieve[i] = i
            for j in range(i * i, n, i):
                if sieve[j] == 0:
                    sieve[j] = i
    return sieve


def sum_of_divisors(n, sieve):
    assert 0 < n
    s = 1
    j = n
    while j > 1:
        i = sieve[j]
        j //= i
        m = i * i
        while sieve[j] == i:
            j //= i
            m *= i
        s *= (m - 1) // (i - 1)
    return s


sieve = make_sieve(28123 + 1)

s = 28123 * (28123 + 1) // 2
ab_dense = []
ab_sparse = [False] * (28123 + 1)
for i in range(1, 28123 + 1):
    ab_sparse[i] = sum_of_divisors(i, sieve) > 2 * i
    i2 = i // 2
    if i % 2 == 0 and ab_sparse[i2]:
        ab_dense.append(i2)
    for j in ab_dense:
        if ab_sparse[i - j]:
            s -= i
            break

print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

мой код даёт 4179871

```
# проверить, является ли число избыточным
def is_redundant(value):
    res = 0

    for i in range(1, value):
        if value % i == 0:
            res += i

    return res > value


# проверить, является ли число суммой двух избыточных чисел
def is_redundans_sum(value, redundants):
    # рассмотреть все варианты первого слагаемого
    for i in redundants:
        sub = value - i

        # проверить - является ли разность избыточным числом
        if sub in redundants:
            return True

    return False


# получить список всех избыточных чисел
limit = 28123

redundants = {i for i in range(1, limit + 1) if is_redundant(i) is True}

# определить какое число является суммой двух избыточных чисел
res = 0
for value in range(1, limit + 1):
    res += 0 if is_redundans_sum(value, redundants) is True else value

print(res)
```

работает 26,2 сек, основная оптимизация сделана на определении суммы - я прохожу по всем избыточным числам, а затем проверяю, является ли разность избыточным числом (для множества поиск числа в списке выполняется за очень короткое время)

**версия 2:**

12.8 сек:

основное время уходит на составление списка избыточных чисел (O(n^2) сложность все таки)

главная оптимизация - множители надо считать только до половины числа, дальше множителей нет

второстепенная оптимизация - рассматривать первый множитель только до проверяемого числа и не больше, но для этого приходится использовать список, а не множество (так как нужны отсортированные числа, а множество это обеспечить не может)

```
# проверить, является ли число избыточным
def is_redundant(value):
    res = 1

    for i in range(2, value // 2 + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            res += i

    return res > value


# проверить, является ли число суммой двух избыточных чисел
def is_redundans_sum(value, redundants, redundants_s):
    # рассмотреть все варианты первого слагаемого
    for i in redundants:

        # если число превышает первое слагаемое - не рассматривать числа множители дальше
        if i > value:
            break

        # вычислить второе слагаемое
        sub = value - i

        # проверить - является ли разность избыточным числом
        if sub in redundants_s:
            return True

    return False


# получить список всех избыточных чисел
limit = 28123

redundants = [i for i in range(1, limit + 1) if is_redundant(i)]
redundants_s = set(redundants)

# определить какое число является суммой двух избыточных чисел
res = 0
for value in range(1, limit + 1):
    res += 0 if is_redundans_sum(value, redundants, redundants_s) else value

print(res)
```

Для красоты функцию is_redundant можно записать как

```
def is_redundant(value):
    res = sum(i for i in range(1, value // 2 + 1) if value % i == 0)

    return res > value
```

на скорость это никак не влияет :(

**вариант 3:**

2.24 сек:

основная оптимизация - иной подход к функции `is_redundant` определения избыточности числа (O(n^1.5) сложность)

проходим до множителя `sqrt(value)` включительно

если число `i` является множителем, то и `value // i` является множителем, учитываем и его, но...только 1 раз, для чего используется список всех чисел от `0` до `value`:

```
def is_redundant(value):
    res = 1

    dividers = [0] * value
    dividers[0] = 1

    for i in range(2, int(value**0.5) + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            res += i

            dividers[i] = 1

            i2 = value // i

            if dividers[i2] == 0:
                res += i2
                dividers[i2] = 1

    return res > value
```